# Strange effects when chaining results in struts 2

Tags: struts2

When an error event occurs I am chaining the result to an error action, this works okay when its all happening in the same namespace but when chaining across namespaces the results of the chained action are in the chaining actions namespace.

```
<package name="mynamespace-htm" namespace="/mynamespace/htm" extends="mybase-base">
    <action name="newsItem"  class="com.mypackage.control.GetNewsItemAction">
        <result name="success">newsItem.jsp</result>
        <result name="error" type="chain">
            <param name="actionName">invalidSite</param>
            <param name="namespace">/mynamespace</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="mynamespace" namespace="/mynamespace" extends="mybase-base">
    <action name="invalidSite" class="com.mypackage.control.GetInvalidSiteAction">
        <result name="success">commonviews/invalidSite.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

If I access the `newsItem` action in a way that causes an error result I get an exception `javax.servlet.ServletException: File "/mynamespace/htm/commonviews/invalidSite.jsp" not found` why is it trying to find the file relative to the original namespace `mynamespace/htm` instead of `mynamespace`?

Comment: In general chaining is not the best way to use, there are other way to do this.I suggest not to use chaining.

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi thanks, I am aware that there are other ways but due to the location of struts within the system and the way it is used `actionRedirect` is not suitable, and as most requests arrive at the struts servlet via an include I cannot use httpheader to pass back to a global error page in the `web.xml`, this is intended to be a stopgap solution

Comment: Are you sure your `error` result is being executed? Could you post full stacktrace.

Comment: Makes sense to me. redirect/redirect-action (which you are not using redirects the url), with chain the url stays the same, but you execute further code. There are relative namespaces and in your case you used a relative resource path (the file - which has no leading slash). Simply specify the full path to the resource and the issue will go away. To be clear the URL in play is the one against which relative paths will be mapped. This was not tested, I always use absolute paths to views (well if they are files).